# Illegal start for array

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish this code, which iterates through a given file and prints a chart counting the leading ones. However, I get an error for "(47,42): ')' expected" as well as "(47,48): illegal start of expression". The code was working fine (minus skipping comments within lines; which I added the Boolean hasComment and the for, ifs and while loops) Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** I'm still not able to get the program to print, but when I remove the hasComment method and the nested for, if and while loops, it works fine. However, the hasComment method and those loops are suppose to skip comments, but not whole lines. For example, if a line in the file reads "(* comment *) 89", I need to skip the comment but read 89. Any pointers or guidance would be great, thanks!

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Benford {

  public static boolean hasComment(String s) {

      return s.indexOf("(*") != -1 && s.indexOf("*)") != -1;

  }


  // Reads file and creates array

  private static int[] countDigits(Scanner input) {

      int[] count = new int[10];

      while (input.hasNextInt()) {

          int n = input.nextInt();

          count[firstDigit(n)]++;

      }

      return count;

  }


  // Display chart

  private static void reportResults(int[] count) {

      System.out.println("Digit Count Frequency");

      for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {

          double freq = count[i] * .10;

          System.out.printf("%-5d %-5d %.2f\n", i, count[i], freq);

      }

  }


  // Returns first digit

  private static int firstDigit(int n) {

      int result = Math.abs(n);

      while (result >= 10) {

          result = result / 10;

      }

      return result;

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


      System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");

      String name = in.nextLine();


      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(name));

      int[] count = countDigits(Scanner input);


      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

          if (!input.hasNext()) {

              break;

          }

          // else

          String line = input.next();

          String s = " ";

          if (hasComment(line)) {


              int endCommentIndex = line.indexOf("*)");

              line = line.substring(endCommentIndex + 2);

          }

          while (line.charAt(0) == ' ') {

              s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

          }

          reportResults(count);

      }

  }

}
```

Comment: Recommend you to start using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. It's time to get serious about the code you write.

Answer (score 1):

You had the problem here.

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(name));

  int[] count = countDigits(Scanner input);
```

Instead you should just pass the reference.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(name));
 int[] count = countDigits(input);
```

This is not allowed, the scape sequence "\s+" in

```
s = s.replaceAll("\s+", "");
```

valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \

Comment: Actually that's one of two. Find the other, gain a vote :)

Comment: Thanks jonhid! Please see the comment I left to Stefan's response. Now my code prints nothing after entering a filename. Thanks again!